# parent child indexing in apache solr

Tags: solr

I'm new to Apache solr search. I'm not getting ho to get solr search result with child documents.

**My entity in data-config.xml**

```
<entity  name="products" query="SELECT DISTINCT IDENTIFIER,PDT_NAME,PDT_DESCRIPTION FROM **PARENT_TABLE**"
    deltaQuery="SELECT IDENTIFIER FROM PARENT_TABLE WHERE LAST_MODIFIED_DATE > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'">
        <field column="IDENTIFIER" name="pdtid" />  
        <field column="PDT_NAME" name="productname" />  
        <field column="PDT_DESCRIPTION" name="productdescription" />
        <entity name="productVersions" child="true" query="SELECT DISTINCT child_id , child_name FROM  WHERE IDENTIFIER = '${**products.IDENTIFIER**}'"> 
                <field column="IDENTIFIER" name="productVersions.pdtesat" />
                <field column="VERSION_NUMBER" name="productVersions.versionnum" />
                <field column="DISPLAY_NAME" name="productVersions.displayname" />                                
        </entity>
</entity>
```

**field details in managed-schema file:**

```
<field name="pdtid" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="productname" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="productnamerrr" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="productdescription" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="productVersions.childid" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="productVersions.versionnum" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="productVersions.displayname" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

I'm expecting my solr result should be :

```
 "response":{"numFound":26,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "productdescription":" Java",
        "productnamerrr":"pdtid",
        "pdtid":"6591",
        "child_docs" : [
                "productVersions":[
                            "productVersions.childid":"123"
                            "productVersions.versionnum":"V1"
                            "productVersions.displayname":"disp"],
                "productVersions":[
                    "productVersions.childid":"456"
                    "productVersions.versionnum":"V2"
                    "productVersions.displayname":"disp2"]
                    ],
        "id":"92689209-dc5f-4ae6-bd3c-d55dbd0e200c",
        "_version_":1599132440456069120},
```

Please help me in getting the multiple child docs in json format after indexing.

---

May 2nd edit.

My query result from solr search like below.

```
"response":{"numFound":38,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "productdescription":" JIRA provides issue (bug) and project tracking 
                               for the software development team.",
        "productnamerrr":"Atlassian JIRA",
        "productVersions":
                ["childid:6.x,versionnum:Jira 6.x,displayname :Withdrawn",
                 "childid:2.0.3,versionnum:Atlassian JIRA,displayname:Planning",
                 "childid:JIRA Server 5.0.1 - 6.3.15,versionnum:JIRA - JEditor,displayname :Withdrawn",
                 "childid:1.x,versionnum:Jira 1.x,displayname :Withdrawn"
                ],
        "id":"0b5ba528-ef7a-49ba-a97b-2ea94922cbb5",
        "_version_":1599297669816123392},
```

---

Edited on May 3-2018

returned data is correct. But the i'm expecting in parent child documents explicitly.   getting child docs as below.

```
"productVersions":["childid:6.x,versionnum:Jira 6.x,displayname :Withdrawn",
             "childid:2.0.3,versionnum:Atlassian JIRA,displayname:Planning",
             "childid:JIRA Server 5.0.1 - 6.3.15,versionnum:JIRA - JEditor,displayname :Withdrawn",
             "childid:1.x,versionnum:Jira 1.x,displayname :Withdrawn"
            ],
```

Expecting like below.

```
    "productVersions":[ 
                    "productVersions.childid":"123"
                    "productVersions.versionnum":"V1"
                   "productVersions.displayname":"disp"],
"productVersions":[
                    "productVersions.childid":"456"
                    "productVersions.versionnum":"V2"
                    "productVersions.displayname":"disp2"]
                    ],
```

How can i change the query to get child docs separately as a separate entity.??

Comment: So what is your query result? What is your query? What is the result if you search `*:*` to return all documents?

Comment: My query result from solr search like below.

Comment: But what is the query? What is wrong in the returned data?